# how to fetch the nested data from multiple tables using withRelated attribute in bookshelf ORM?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, bookshelf.js

I have three tables (post_like, user,posts). I am using the relations to capture the names of the users who have liked a particular post. I am getting the user_id but I am unable to fetch the user names.

```
var post = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'posts',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    postLike: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(post);
    }
});


var postLike = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'posts_like',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    post: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(post);
    },
    user: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(user);
    }
});

var user = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'users',
    hasTimestamps: true,
    post: function() {
        return this.hasMany(post);
    },
    postLike: function() {
        return this.belongsToMany(postLike);
    }
});
```

I am getting the response like this

```
    posts:{
        id:XXX,
        summary:XXX,
        author:{
            name: XXX,
            bio:XXX
        },
        like:[{
            user_id:XXX
        },
        {
            user_id:XXX
        }]
  }
```

I need something like this

```
posts:{
            id:XXX,
            summary:XXX,
            author:{
                name: XXX,
                bio:XXX
            },
            like:[{
                user_id:XXX,
                user:{
                    name:XXX
                }
            },
            {
                user_id:XXX,
                user:{
                    name:XXX
                }
            }]
      }
```

Comment: Could you add the statement you are using to fetch data? And your sample answer does not match the definition, e.g. no 'author' or 'like' relationships.

Comment: I am using fetchAll method of bookshelf.
By author I mean author of the post.

Comment: Your model definitions have no 'author' and no 'like' defined, so they are inconsistent with the sample data you provided. Adding the code that is returning the list without user details will help understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks  @ flaviodesousa.
I have resolved the issue using knex.raw query of bookshelf.